# Fillna() in column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have created a small dictionary, where a specific title is assigned a median age.

```
        Age
Title   
Master. 3.5
Miss.   21.0
Mr.     30.0
Mrs.    35.0
other   44.5
```

Now I want to use this dictionary to fill the missing values in a single column in a dataframe, based on that title. So, for rows where the "Age" is missing, and the title = "Master.", I want to insert the value 3.5 and so on.

I tried this piece of code, but it does not work; it doesn't produce an error, but it also doesn't replace the missing values. What am I doing wrong?

```
for title in piv.keys():
    train[["Age"]][train["Title"]==title].fillna(piv[title], inplace=True)
```

where "piv" is the name of the dictionary, and "train" is the name of the dataframe.

Also, is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
PassengerId Survived    Pclass  Name    Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Ticket  Fare    Cabin   Embarked    Title
0   1   0   3   Braund, Mr. Owen Harris male    22.0    1   0   A/5 21171   7.2500  NaN S   Mr.
1   2   1   1   Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...   female  38.0    1   0   PC 17599    71.2833 C85 C   Mrs.

{'Master.': 3.5, 'Miss.': 21.0, 'Mr.': 30.0, 'Mrs.': 35.0, 'other': 44.5}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the dataframe and the python structure of the dictionary?

Comment: I tried to add a couple of rows, but it looks a bit messy here. Not sure how I can format it to look like a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
train['Age'] = train.groupby('Title')['Age'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Another option:

```
pivdict = piv.set_index('Title').squeeze().to_dict()

train['Age'] = train['Age'].fillna(train['Title'].map(pivdict))
```

Answer (score 0):

One method:

```
# create lookup dictionary
title = ['Master', 'Miss.', 'Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'other']
age = [3.5, 21, 30, 35, 44]
title_dict = dict(zip(title, age))

# mock dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Charles', 'Mary'],
                  'Age': [12, 27, None, None],
                  'Title': ['Master', 'Miss.', 'Mr.', 'other']})

# if age is Na then look it up in dictionary
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(df['Title'].map(title_dict))
```

Input:

```
      Name   Age   Title
0      Bob  12.0  Master
1    Alice  27.0   Miss.
2  Charles   NaN     Mr.
3     Mary   NaN   other
```

Output:

```
      Name   Age   Title
0      Bob  12.0  Master
1    Alice  27.0   Miss.
2  Charles  30.0     Mr.
3     Mary  44.0   other
```